# How to deploy relationship in pivot of three model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, permissions, eloquent-relationship

I'm developing a role and permissions based on laravel framework.

I have 3 models :

```
Weblog
User
Permissions
```

This is pivot table

```
user_id , weblog_id , permission_id
```

Now, **a user** can have a weblog with permission id 1,2 and another weblog with permission 1,2,3,4

How can I deploy relationships? and how can I check user permissions when managing a weblog. (middleware and ...)

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think, your best bet is to see the pivot table as a Model. So you can define 1:n-relationships between those models.

Comment: Is the relation between User and Weblog One-to-Many or Many-to-Many - means can one Weblog record be associated with multiple users or is it that one Weblog record is associated with only one User

Comment: @Donkarnash relation between weblog and user is  Many-to-Many

Comment: what code are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the fact that Permission are specific to Weblog

Say the pivot table is called `permission_user_weblog`

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function weblogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Weblog::class, 'permission_user_weblog');
    }

    public function permissionsFor(int $weblogId)
    {
        $permissionIds = null;

        $this->weblogs()
            ->where('id', $weblogId)
            ->with('permissions')
            ->get()
            ->each(function($weblog) use(&$permissionIds) {
                $permissionIds = $weblog->permissions->pluck('id');             
            });

        return $permissionIds;
    }
}


class Weblog extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'permission_user_weblog');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'permission_user_weblog');
    }
}


class Permission extends Model
{
    public function weblogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Weblog::class, 'permission_user_weblog');
    }
}
```

Then you can check anywhere for whether logged in user has specific permission for a specific weblog

```php
public function update(Request $request, $weblogId)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $permissions = $user->permissionsFor($weblogId);

    //Check whether the logged in user has permission identified by id 1 or 4 for weblog
    $can = !! $permissions->intersect([1,4])->count();

    //Do rest of processing
}
```

Comment: thanks for this solutions, I'm working on it and I'll update here.

Answer (score 0):

your Weblog,User,Permission has ManyToMany Relation, its a kind of **odd** but if you want to have this kind of relation its not a problem.

just consider **each pair** a **ManyToMany**. and every one of those can have a **hasMany** to **Pivot** (i named it Access) too (based on your needs).

User model:

```
class User extends Model{

/**
      * retrive weblogs
      *
      * @return BelongsToMany weblogs
      */
     public function weblogs()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(App\WebLog::class,'accesses_table')
                        ->withPivot("permission_id")
                        ->using(App\Access::class);
     }

/**
      * retrive permissions
      *
      * @return BelongsToMany permissions
      */
     public function permissions()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(App\Permission::class,'accesses_table')
                        ->withPivot("weblog_id")
                        ->using(App\Access::class);
     }

/**
      * retrive access
      *
      * @return hasMany [description]
      */
     public function accesses()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(App\Access::class, "user_id");
     }
}
```

Weblog model:

```
class Weblog extends Model{

/**
      * retrive users
      *
      * @return BelongsToMany users
      */
     public function users()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class,'accesses_table')
                        ->withPivot("permission_id")
                        ->using(App\Access::class);
     }

/**
      * retrive permissions
      *
      * @return BelongsToMany permissions
      */
     public function permissions()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(App\Permission::class,'accesses_table')
                        ->withPivot("user_id")
                        ->using(App\Access::class);
     }

/**
      * retrive access
      *
      * @return hasMany [description]
      */
     public function accesses()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(App\Access::class, "weblog_id");
     }
}
```

Permission model:

```
class Permission extends Model{

/**
      * retrieve users
      *
      * @return BelongsToMany users
      */
     public function users()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class,'accesses_table')
                        ->withPivot("weblog_id")
                        ->using(App\Access::class);
     }

/**
      * retrieve weblogs
      *
      * @return BelongsToMany weblogs
      */
     public function weblogs()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany(App\Weblog::class,'accesses_table')
                        ->withPivot("user_id")
                        ->using(App\Access::class);
     }

/**
      * retrive access
      *
      * @return hasMany [description]
      */
     public function accesses()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(App\Access::class, "permission_id");
     }
}
```

and you can have a **model** for your **pivot**, which i named it **Access** :

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Access extends Pivot
{

    public $incrementing = true;

public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
    }

    public function weblog()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Weblog::class);
    }

    public function permission()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Permission::class);
    }

}
```